# How to resolve injected instances in Vue.js using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, vue.js

According to the [official document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject), it seems that we can use dependency injection feature as long as we stay on object-based structure.

Here's my question. I'm using TypeScript to achieve this goal (class-based). I'm going to use [`Inversify`](http://inversify.io) as an IoC container. My initial idea was something like:

**`DependencyConfig.ts`**:

```
import { Container } from "inversify";
import "reflect-metadata";
import Warrior from "./interfaces/Warrior";
import { Ninja } from "./models/Warrior";

let container = new Container();

container.bind<Warrior>(Symbol("Warrior")).to(Ninja);

export default container;
```

**`App.ts`**:

```
import container from "./DependencyConfig";

@Component({
  name: "App",
  provide: container
})
export default class App extends Vue {
}
```

When I checked in my browser's dev console, I was able to see the `container` has been set to the `_provided` field. Here's `Hello.ts`, the child component of `App.ts`:

**`Hello.ts`**:

```
@Component({
  name: "Hello",
  inject: [ "container" ]
})
export default class Hello extends Vue {
  created (): void {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

As `App.ts` could access to `Hello.ts` through `vue-router`, it didn't register `Hello.ts` as a child component. I was expecting the injected container should appear on `_injected` or something similar. However, I couldn't find it. I changed the `inject` property value from `"container"` to `{ "container": Symbol("Container") }` but I couldn't still find it.

**Service Locator**:

It works fine to use a service locator instead of the `provide/inject` pair:

```
// App.ts
@Component({
  name: "App"
})
export default class App extends Vue {
}

// Hello.ts
import container from "./DependencyConfig";

@Component({
  name: "Hello"
})
export default class Hello extends Vue {
  created (): void {
    var ninja = container.get<Ninja>(Symbol("Warrior"));
    console.log(ninja.name);
  }
}
```

However, I want to avoid using the service locator pattern here. Did I miss something while using the `provide/inject` pair for dependency injection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. If we use [`vue-class-component`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) and [`vue-property-decorator`](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator), we can achieve this goal – using the `provide`/`inject` pair. Here's my code snippet:

```
// App.vue
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from "vue-class-component";
import SERVICE_IDENTIFIER from "./models/Identifiers";
import container from "./configs/DependencyConfigs";

@Component({
  name: "App",
  // Provides IoC container at the top level of VueComponent
  provide: {
    [SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.CONTAINER]: container
  }
})
export default class App extends Vue {
}
</script>
```

At the top-most Vue component, `App.vue`, we provide the `container` instance so that its all child component can consume it. Here's one of its child component, `Ninja.vue`:

```
// Ninja.vue
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";

// Imports both Component and Inject decorators from vue-property-decorator,
// instead of vue-class-component
import { Component, Inject } from "vue-property-decorator";

import { Container } from "inversify";

import SERVICE_IDENTIFIER from "../models/Identifiers";
import { Ninja as _Ninja } from "../models/Warrior";

@Component({
  name: "Ninja"
})
export default class Ninja extends Vue {
  public warrior: string;
  public weapon: string;

  // IoC container provided from App.ts is injected here
  @Inject(SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.CONTAINER)
  private _container: Container;

  private _ninja: _Ninja;

  created (): void {
    this._ninja = this._container.get<_Ninja>(SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.WARRIOR);
    this.warrior = this._ninja.name;
    this.weapon = this._ninja.weapon.name;
  }
}
</script>
```

The child component uses the `@Inject(Symbol)` decorator to resolve injected `container` instance from `App.vue`.

I wrote a blog post about this in both [English](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/03/22/dependency-injection-in-vuejs-app-with-typescript/) and [Korean](http://blog.aliencube.org/ko/2017/03/21/using-ioc-container-in-vuejs-typescript-app/) about this.

HTH

Comment: You are actually describing the service locator pattern, see https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator. So this is not a solution.

Comment: @FrankLiepert Indeed, it's rather a service locator pattern. SL is another type of DI. AFAIK, SL is the only way to achieve DI in Vue.js.